# How to enable Http byte range request in ThingsBoard?

Tags: spring, thingsboard, ota, thingsboard-gateway, range-requests

I would like to use [RAUC](https://rauc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) update framework together with ThingsBoard as server. The issue is that for delta updates on RAUC side I need server to support HTTP range request, from my limited testing on ThingsBoard I found out it doesnt support it out of box, it only supports the chunked transfer-encoding.

Is there any way I can enable it, for example by including some plugin?

Sorry if my question is vague. I work on embedded stuff and server side is a black box for me.